# FlatBuffers and NULL value

Tags: serialization, flatbuffers

What is canonical way to store NULL value in FlatBuffers ?

I have

```
ExpirationDate     *int64
```

I understand why FlatBuffers is not defining NULL. But I do not understand how to handle that properly. Should I have extra bool field or make value a array?

```
ExpirationDate     [int64]
```

vs

```
ExpirationDate     int64
ExpirationDateNull bool
```

For tables may be I can use also `union`.

Comment: "I understand why FlatBuffers is not defining NULL".  Why so??

Answer (score 6):

A third option is `struct NullableInt64 { i:int64 }` and then in table have a field of type `NullableInt64`. When this field is not present, the accessor function will return `NULL`. And because it a struct, it will take the same space on the wire as a naked int64 (they're both 8 bytes and are stored inline in the parent).

Answer (score 4):

For storing values like int32 / int64 etc. You can directly keep the scalars in the table.

But in your case you have an indirection, which can be mimiced by an indirection created by non-scalars in flatbuffers.

Non-scalars are struct, array, and table.

So you may try :

```
Struct IntPtr 
{ 
val:int64
} 

Table Expiration 
{ 
ExpirationDate:IntPtr; 
}
```

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't see you were answering at the same time :)

Comment: Yeah.  Coincidence :)